# How do I stop the preview of webpages in internet explorer for windows 7 when clicking on icon?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, tabs, preview

Whenever I click on the internet explorer icon on the bottom left in Windows 7, instead of just opening IE it will expand all of the tabs open and show a preview. How do I change this so that it just expands IE when I click on the icon?

Comment: actually the previews are triggered by mousing over the taskbar icon, not clicking. clicking should give focus to the tab that had focus when you shrank IE. (I just tested this on my own IE.) If you want another IE, clicking the taskbar icon won't get it for you, you'll need to right click and then choose from the jumplist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to right click over the taskbar, go to properties and the dropdown where it says 'Taskbar buttons select 'Never combine'.

Unfortunately this will affect all windows.

If you want to open a new instance of IE, right click over the icon and select the 'Internet Explorer' option. This will launch a new IE window.